# How to remove unnessecary parts in an plot (Maple)

Tags: plot, maple

A few minutes ago; I made an answer to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/407341/8581). As can be seen, the desired volume is really surrounded by $x=0,~y=0,~z=0,~x+y=1,~x^2+z=1$. My question is how can I make the plot in which I remove the unnecessary parts from the output. Indeed, on $xy-$plane, we don't need the triangle part with $(1,0),(1,1),(0,1)$. Thanks for your time and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
plot3d(1-x^2, x=0..1-y, y=0..1, filled=true, style=surface);
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I wanted to find you at the link you noted in your profile, but you were not on today. :-)

Comment: If you have time please take a look at this [one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/407798/8581). Thanks